# Get resulting rectangle from two overlapping rectangles

Tags: c#, algorithm, mathematics

I have a function that creates a rectangle from two rectangles that overlap, I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do it purely mathematically rather than lots of `if` statements to check `min` and `max` the way I currently have setup.

This is my function

```
    public static bool Overlaps(this Bounds a, Bounds bounds, out Bounds result)
    {
        result = new Bounds();
        //they don't overlap
        if (!a.Intersects(bounds)) return false;

        float minX;
        float maxX;
        float minZ;
        float maxZ;

        if (a.min.x > bounds.min.x)
            minX = a.min.x;
        else
            minX = bounds.min.x;

        if (a.max.x < bounds.max.x)
            maxX = a.max.x;
        else
            maxX = bounds.max.x;

        if (a.min.z > bounds.min.z)
            minZ = a.min.z;
        else
            minZ = bounds.min.z;

        if (a.max.z < bounds.max.z)
            maxZ = a.max.z;
        else
            maxZ = bounds.max.z;

        // using XZ plane for debug
        Vector3 min = new Vector3(minX,0,minZ);
        Vector3 max = new Vector3(maxX,0,maxZ);
        result.SetMinMax(min,max);
        return true;
    }
```

Here it is in action

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float minX;
float maxX;
float minZ;
float maxZ;
```

The declarations can be inlined so that it is clearer when they are being set. However, in geometry and other applications it may be preferable to declare them like this.

```
if (a.max.x < bounds.max.x)
            maxX = a.max.x;
        else
            maxX = bounds.max.x;
```

These conditions can be replaced with calls to `Math.max` and `Math.min`.

The variable names such as `minX` and `maxX` seem to be reversed; `minX` seems to be referring to `maxX` and vice-versa. I am not very familiar with geometry so I don't know if my suggestion is correct to swap the names.

After applying these suggestions, the method becomes the following:

```
  public static bool Overlaps(this Bounds a, Bounds bounds, out Bounds result)
    {
        result = new Bounds();
        //they don't overlap
        if (!a.Intersects(bounds)) return false;

        float minX = Math.Max(a.min.x, bounds.min.x);
        float maxX = Math.Min(a.max.x, bounds.max.x);

        float minZ = Math.Max(a.min.z, bounds.min.z);
        float maxZ = Math.Min(a.max.z, bounds.max.z);

        // using XZ plane for debug
        Vector3 min = new Vector3(minX, 0, minZ);
        Vector3 max = new Vector3(maxX, 0, maxZ);
        result.SetMinMax(min, max);
        return true;
    }
```

Edit: to respond to the comment (minimizing if statements), it could be expressed as:

```
  public static bool Overlaps(this Bounds a, Bounds bounds, out Bounds result)
    {
        result = new Bounds();

        float minX = Math.Max(a.min.x, bounds.min.x);
        float maxX = Math.Min(a.max.x, bounds.max.x);

        float minZ = Math.Max(a.min.z, bounds.min.z);
        float maxZ = Math.Min(a.max.z, bounds.max.z);

        // using XZ plane for debug
        Vector3 min = new Vector3(minX, 0, minZ);
        Vector3 max = new Vector3(maxX, 0, maxZ);
        result.SetMinMax(min, max);
        return !a.Intersects(bounds);
    }
```

This would be slightly less efficient; I don't know if this is valid as if the `Vector3` class will accept input which did not pass `.Intersects`.

Comment: But that function call is doing the same thing surely? Other than cleaning up the code its not reduced the if statements and turning it into a purely mathematical approach.

Comment: @WDUK I have updated my answer with an alternative approach with no `if` statements.

Comment: It's much cleaner with the early exist code. Plus porbalby more effecient too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is correct to write to the output parameter `result` when you return false. Maybe you should return the result or null instead.

Apart from that I would yet make @alexyorke 's solution more compact (assuming `Bounds` have constructor from min/max) by getting rid of all the intermediate variables:

```
public static Bounds GetOverlap(this Bounds a, Bounds bounds)
{
    if (!a.Intersects(bounds)) return null;

    return new Bounds(
        new Vector3(
            Math.Max(a.min.x, bounds.min.x),
            0,
            Math.Max(a.min.z, bounds.min.z)
        ),
        new Vector3(
            Math.Min(a.max.x, bounds.max.x),
            0,
            Math.Min(a.max.z, bounds.max.z)
        )
    );
}
```

You may still define the shorthand, but I would suggest omitting the output parameter in which case it becomes alias of `Intersects` anyway, so maybe it is useless:

```
public static bool Overlaps(this Bounds a, Bounds bounds)
{
    return a.Intersects(bounds);
}
```

And btw if you want to speed it up a little bit, you may look into the `Intersects` function and you are likely to see that some things that you do in the `Overlaps` function are done there too. Reimplementing `Overlaps` without calling `Intersects` may then be faster, but since you haven't provided the `Intersects` function, I cannot help here.

Comment: Structs can't be null and a bounds of zero returned will still require me to check if the result has a valid bounds to draw. So I opted for the bool / out option.